# TCL - how to know how much time a function has worked?

Tags: time, timestamp, tcl, proc-object

Say I have a **proc** and the proc consists of several statements and function calls. How I can know how much time the function has taken so far?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

a very crude example would be something like:

```
set TIME_start [clock clicks -milliseconds]
...do something...
set TIME_taken [expr [clock clicks -milliseconds] - $TIME_start]
```

Using the time proc, you can do the following:

```
% set tt [time {set x [expr 23 * 34]}]
38 microseconds per iteration
```

Answer (score 5):

To measure the time some code has taken, you either use `time` or `clock`.

The `time` command will run its script argument and return a description of how long the script took, in milliseconds (plus some descriptive text, which is trivial to chop off with `lindex`). If you're really doing performance analysis work, you can supply an optional count argument that makes the script be run repeatedly, but for just general monitoring you can ignore that.

The `clock` command lets you get various sorts of timestamps (as well as doing formatting, parsing and arithmetic with times). The coarsest is got with `clock seconds`, which returns the amount of time since the beginning of the Unix epoch (in seconds computed with civil time; that's what you want unless you're doing something specialized). If you need more detail, you should use `clock milliseconds` or `clock microseconds`. There's also `clock clicks`, but it's not typically defined what unit that's counting in (unless you pass the `-milliseconds` or `-microseconds` option). It's up to you to turn the timestamps into something useful to you.

If you're timing things on Tcl 8.4 (or before!) then you're constrained to using `time`, `clock seconds` or `clock clicks` (and even the `-microseconds` option is absent; there's no microsecond-resolution timer exposed in 8.4). In that case, you should consider upgrading to 8.5, as it's generally faster. Faster is Good! (If you're using pre-8.4, definitely upgrade as you're enormously behind on the support front.)

Answer (score 1):

To tell how long a function has taken, you can either use the `time` command (wrapped around the function call) or use `clock clicks` to get the current time before and then during the function.  The `time` option is simple but can only time a whole function (and will only give you a time when the function returns).  Using `clock clicks` can be done several times, but you will need to subtract the current time from the starting time yourself.

Comment: For example I run my TCL script and I want to measure the time elapsed. How I can do that?

Comment: @Narek: I updated my answer for that; I also edited your question to clarify that you are asking about elapsed time, not future time.

Comment: Please write an example with clock clicks to measure the time a function was running.

Comment: I can't understand what does "clock clicks" returns. What is "high-resolution time value"? (See here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/4615 )

Comment: @Narek: I would use `clock clicks -milliseconds` since that returns the time in known units.

Answer (score 0):

In case your really looking for some kind of profiler, have a look at the profiler package in Tcllib:
http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/profiler.html